# Iterators on ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

ConcurrentHashMap [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) states that

> They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators
>   are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

But below code output results like two threads can run on iterators at the same time.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,Boolean> ref = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Boolean>();
    new Thread("Insertion"){
        public  void run(){
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                ref.put(""+i,Boolean.TRUE); 
            }
        }
    }.start();


    new Thread("Iterator_1"){
        public  void run(){
            Iterator itr = ref.keySet().iterator();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"" + itr.next());
            }
        }
    }.start();


    new Thread("Iterator_2"){
        public  void run(){
            Iterator itr = ref.keySet().iterator();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"" + itr.next());
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Output shows both iterators are working together. Please help to understand this javadoc statement.

```
Thread[Iterator_1,5,main]67
Thread[Iterator_2,5,main]81
Thread[Iterator_1,5,main]2
Thread[Iterator_2,5,main]59
Thread[Iterator_1,5,main]81
Thread[Iterator_2,5,main]40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the javadoc means is that you shouldn't share *the same* iterator instance across two different threads.  In your example, each thread creates its own iterator instance -- this is correct and safe.

What you should *not* do is this (sleeps removed because they're irrelevant):

```
final Iterator itr = ref.keySet().iterator();

new Thread("Iterator_1"){
    public  void run(){
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"" + itr.next());
        }
    }
}.start();

new Thread("Iterator_2"){
    public  void run(){
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"" + itr.next());
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Do you know any perfomance limitation on how many iterator objects i can create out of one concurrent object? Because around 50 threads are requiring iterator() in my system...

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar, you should ask that as a separate question.